# Java Spring how to set up multicore Solr configuration

Tags: java, spring, solr

Basically I copy pasted the multicore configuration from http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/solr.repositories.html and then adjusted a bit, however it does not work, because I need to add corename-SolrClient to the ClientFactory. But do I just create the SolrCLient out of the blue? I want it all to match the cores that are running on the server on my machine. This is the configuration class for the solr:

```
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_SOLR_SERVER_URL = "solr.host";


      @Resource
      private Environment environment;

      @Bean
      public SolrClientFactory solrClientFactory() {
          MulticoreSolrClientFactory factory =  new MulticoreSolrClientFactory(
                  new HttpSolrClient(environment.getRequiredProperty(
                          PROPERTY_NAME_SOLR_SERVER_URL) ));
          return factory;
      }

      @Bean (name = "SolrTemplateMap")
      public Map<Language, SolrTemplate> solrTemplateList(){
          HashMap<Language, SolrTemplate> map = new HashMap<>();
          for (Language l : Language.values()){
              SolrTemplate template = new SolrTemplate (solrClientFactory());
              template.setSolrCore(l.toString());
              map.put( l, template);
          }
          return map;
      }
```

I tried adding

```
for (Language l : Language.values()){
              factory.addSolrClientForCore(new HttpSolrClient(url + "/solr/" + l.toString()), l.toString());
          }
```

in the factory bean, however it doesn't solve anything. `Language` is an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late reply, not sure if this will benefit you but I hope it helps somebody at least. Something like this got me working.

```
  @Bean (name = "SolrTemplateMap")
  public Map<Language, SolrTemplate> solrTemplateList(){
      HashMap<Language, SolrTemplate> map = new HashMap<>();
      for (Language l : Language.values()){
          SolrTemplate template = new SolrTemplate (configureHttpSolrServer(l));
          map.put( l, template);
      }
      return map;
  }

private SolrServer configureHttpSolrServer(String baseURL) {
        HttpSolrServerFactoryBean factoryBean = new HttpSolrServerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setUrl(baseURL);
        factoryBean.setMaxConnections(100);
        return factoryBean;
}
```